# Find the length of the curve $y(x) = \int_1^x\sqrt{t^3 - 1} \, dt$, $1 \leq x \leq 4$

Tags: plane-curves

Find the length of the curve $y(x) = \int_1^x\sqrt{t^3 - 1} \, dt$, $1 \leq x \leq 4$.

Not sure if I should be using first principle theorem (having some trouble with that) or if there is a simpler/more obvious method.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Use the standard formula for arclength.

Soon you will need $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$. For this, use the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)

The relevant part of the Fundamental Theorem  says that under suitable conditions, if $w=\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$, then $\dfrac{dw}{dx}=f(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that Andre noted above and then search for the following definite integral: $$\int_1^4x^{3/2}dx$$ which gives you the length. It is $62/5$.